# A word for 'single view of information'

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, american-english

I have billing information coming from different sources and I want to provide a single view to all the billing information to users. Just wondering if there is a better single word for *single view of information*.

<sub>Thanks.</sub>

Comment: something along the lines of "one-stop", perhaps, "one-click" but the concept involves "consolidation".

Comment: In enterprise technology jargon, as reprehensible as it may be, such dashboards are known as "360* views". *shudders*

Comment: Thee term "unified" is sometimes used, though it has a bit of plastic feel to it.  If this is to be a (gag!) "customer facing" term it's tricky, since many terms such as "dashboard" are either overused or too "techy" to give customers their "warm fuzzies".

Comment: How about a _report_?

Comment: *dashboard* is a common term for such a layout, especially if it is an array of smaller reports.

Answer (score 4):

If the information is condensed and summarised, then a common word for this is **dashboard**. It might apply even if the information is not summarized.

> "An easy to read, often single page, real-time user interface, showing a graphical presentation of the current status (snapshot) and historical trends of an organization’s key performance indicators (KPIs) - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dashboard_%28business%29

Another very common word for this kind of thing is **portal**.

> A web portal is most often one specially designed Web page which brings information together from diverse sources in a uniform way.  - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_portal

And an acronym I've seen used, but less commonly, is **SPOG** (Single Pane Of Glass).

> Single Pane of Glass is a phrase used by information technology (IT) marketers to describe a management console that integrates information from multiple components into a unified display. - http://searchservervirtualization.techtarget.com/definition/single-pane-of-glass

Answer (score 0):

If you have been involved in the information technology in significant ways, you would realise the word *view* is an *overloaded* word.

An *information view* can be a schema view. It can be an MVC / MVP view. It can be a WSDL. It can be an API.

Perhaps, like others, you meant a portal.

However, most of the time in information design and development, an *information view* is seldom applied to the physical web page, because web pages form only a small portion of the information processing that requires *information views*.

For example, when machines talk to each other using SOAP, they offer each other *services*. A server usually shares or expose a single information view or service API called a WSDL, so that client machines can know within a single view, what information the server machine would process and the structure of information required to interact with it.

Then we can have a single view that joins many relevant entities found in a data repository, to hide the intricacies and minutia to present to the client an abstract that is more aligned to the client's perspective, so that the client does not need to deal with minute specifics that vary from server to server.

Perhaps, you could be asking about a single view of information in an MVC pattern. This view is independent of the viewer's technology, theme or scheme, which could be a machine, web browser, an Android or an iPhone. The panes in the view could be configured according to the human preferences. No matter where or how the client wish to view the information, the process displaying the view would see only one single view. This reduces the programming presentation and response logic from having to deal differently with each type of viewer, because only the implementation of the view needs to change.

Whether you are asking for a portal or information structure, it is very important for the information designer to construct a *unified information architecture*. Without a unified information architecture, it would not be effective or efficient to sustain the functioning of a portal or any information transfer interface, and to avoid confusing the perspective of the viewer.

In fact, the phrase "single view of information" is the technology catch phrase. You have already hit the nail on its head. You don't need another term.

You might prefer *unified information view*.

But what you might be looking for is a *normalized information view* or *normalized information interface*.  When you have information coming from diverse sources, in diverse structures, you need to normalize those information streams into a coherent view and interface. You would normalize both the structure and processes of the information. For example, you would need to normalize the population bases, or use exception methods to process data that behave abnormally. For example, users can't simply merge statistics if the population to be merged are of different bases.

When information is normalized, both the processes synthesizing the information and the clients analysing the information are grounded on a coherent and synchronized understanding of the meaning of the information being exchanged.